# GWcode CatMenu: Do Not Show Empty Children

Tags: gwcode-categories

How do I set [GWcode CatMenu](http://goo.gl/hVkUGj) to not show child categories that have no entries assigned to them? The `show_empty="no"` parameter only seems to work for parent categories.

Here's my code:

```
{exp:gwcode_catmenu style="linear" cat_id="5" active_branch_only="yes"}
    {if cat_id != 5}
        <li><a href="{path='home/products_grid/category/{cat_url_title}'}">{cat_name}</a></li>
    {/if} 
{/exp:gwcode_catmenu}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable the `entry_count` parameter?

```
{exp:gwcode_catmenu 
    style="linear" 
    cat_id="5" 
    active_branch_only="yes" 
    entry_count="yes" 
    show_empty="no"
}
    {if cat_id != 5}
        <li><a href="{path='home/products_grid/category/{cat_url_title}'}">{cat_name}</a></li>
    {/if} 
{/exp:gwcode_catmenu}
```